# Facebook jQuery AJAX JSON call - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, facebook

I'm trying to get JSON data from facebook using the following code:

```
var getFriends = function() {
    var friendsURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/<?= $cookie['uid'] ?>/friends?access_token=<?= $cookie['access_token'] ?>&jsoncallback=?';

    $.getJSON(friendsURL, function(data) {

        var names = "";

        $.each(data.name, function(){
            names += " " + this;
        });

        alert("JSON Data: " + names);
    });

}
```

Every time I run the function I get this error in Chrome: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Any ideas? I made sure to put "jsoncallback=?" at the end of the url to make it return as JSONP but I've run out of solutions now.

Thanks,
-Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`graph.facebook.com` expects `callback` in the querystring, not `jsoncallback`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/javascript), so your URL should look like this to trigger JSONP on their side (currently you're just getting JSON):

```
var friendsURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/<?= $cookie['uid'] ?>/friends?access_token=<?= $cookie['access_token'] ?>&callback=?';
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, that's exactly what I was after!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the official Javascript SDK instead? That call would be:

```
FB.api('/userid/friends', function(response) {
  // response is an array of friends
});
```

The official library will handle the particulars for you so you don't have to worry about all the implementation details.

Comment: Including their whole SDK for a single AJAX request to get some data when you're already using jQuery seems like *tremendous* overkill...especially since removing 4 characters is all that's needed here.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it to jQuery but thanks anyway Nathan, that is a valid answer